# Qt WizardPage back with some explicit function

Tags: qt, wizard

I am a newer to Qt.
I create a QWizard and add some QWizardPage to it. Now I want to back before page by some other way besides the back button, for example: some sinal or some funtion.

In details, I want to operate some funtion in page 2, the show a messagebox in it and provide the choise to return to page 1.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#back ?

Comment: Thank you so much. And do you know how go to a specified page (eg: page 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QWizard` has a slot for `back` (also `next` and `restart` if needed)

You can call the slot manually like a function call

```
wizard->back();
```

or connect it to a custom signal

```
connect(someClass,&class::mysignal,wizard,&QWizard::back);
```

---

When you want a more complex behavior maybe you should look into creating a [non-linear wizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#creating-non-linear-wizards)

Qt has a guide on how to do it in general.

Basically it is about overriding `QWizard::nextId()` and when the wizard wants to figure out where to jump next this function will be called.

---

You cannot jump directly to a certain page though. You have to call `back`/`next`/`restart`

This can be workarounded by this though:

```
while(wizard->currentId() != <desiredID>)
{
     wizard->back();
}
```

Be aware though that you don't get into endless loops if you are already before the page. To go to page 1 `restart` would be a better option. Or a non-linear wizard as mentioned.

Comment: I try to call wizard->back()  in my wizardpage, the wizard is the point of the wizard which it added to. But it doesn't work. 
`void NiuFPage::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    parentwizardpoint->back();

}`

Comment: It's OK now. I connect a wrong function to the clicked signal before.
Thank you so so so much for your detailed information